# Components cannot be accessed after migrating from ionic3 to ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have migrated from ionic v3 to ionic v4 with the help of [Migration from ionic3 to ionic4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/) documentation.

As per the documentation i have installed newer version of angular by doing

$npm install @ionic/angular

Now in all my pages if my try to import the following statement

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

**IonicPage** and **ViewController** is underlined with red line suggesting the error as `Module has no exported member

How to overcome this issue, i am not able the revert back to older version of ionic-angular

Answer (score 0):

They cant be assessed because ionic 4 does support 'Pages' like they used to. Now they just use angular components which you use the router to jump between. I'd advice generating your pages components using the ionic cli that will make a page like component for you, then migrate your logic over.